# SQL regex replace whole phrase only

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2008-r2, replace

```
@text = 'First +Last /(toto salary *0.07)'
```

what is the SQL query to replace "whole phrase only" betwen operator

I mean :

```
  replace(@text , 'toto salary','bobo salary')
  result : 'First +Last /(bobo salary *0.07)'
```

but when :

```
replace(@text , 'toto','') 
NO result because not match whole phrase ('toto salary')
```

by other word , replace phrases between ' * + / - ( )  ' operator

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The following could work:

```
select regexp_replace( 'First +Last /(toto salary *0.07)' , '(/\()toto salary( [*][0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*\))','\1bobo salary\2') from dual;
```

The trick is to put parenthesis around the mandatory part that you want to keep,
in this case the `/(`and the `*0.07)`, and then include those parts by adding `\1` and `\2` and so on in the replacement expression.

Comment: Unfortunately `regexp_replace` is not available in SQL Server

Comment: Add the placeholder before you do the replace:
`replace('/(toto salary ', '/(bobo salary ')`